# All tests are being excluded when using groups in Testng XML suite

Tags: testng

When I attempt to group my tests in the Testng XML suite, all of the test methods are excluded in the test run.

I have written my tests in a way that I want all of the test methods in my class to be run, but only certain classes in the suite to be executed, so I have used class level annotations:

```
@Test (groups={ TestConstrants.Group1})
public class ABCTests extends AbstractIntegrationTest
{

    @Test
public void Test1() throws Exception

    @Test
    public void Test2() throws Exception
}

@Test (groups={ TestConstrants.Group2})
public class DEFTests extends AbstractIntegrationTest
{

    @Test
public void Test3() throws Exception

    @Test
    public void Test4() throws Exception
}
```

My Testng XML is configured for the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="SuiteGroup">
  <test name="TestGroups" preserve-order="true">
    <groups>
    <run>
        <include name="TestConstants.Group1"/>
        <exclude name="TestConstants.Group2"/>
    </run>  
</groups>
    <classes>
      <class name="ABCTests"/>
      <class name="DEFTests"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- TestGroups -->
</suite> <!-- SuiteGroup -->
```

In this example, I would expect only the tests in class ABCTests to be ran, however, it appears all of the tests are being excluded for some reason. I have verified that the methods in the class I am extending (AbstractIntegrationTest) are set to 'alwaysRun = true'.

I know that I could simply not include the classes that I do not want to run, but I will potentially have hundreds of tests and it is much easier to maintain the test suite by group than class.

Answer (score 1):

If you can create a small project showing the problem, email it to me and I'll take a look.

Note: you are using the word "Constrants" in the snippet above, not sure if it's your real code or a harmless typo here.